# Do primes "behave" in this way?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that we choose some real number $\varepsilon >0$.

> Can we always find $n_0(\varepsilon) \in \mathbb N$ such that for every $n> n_0(\varepsilon)$ there is a prime number $p$ such that we have $n<p<n(1+\varepsilon)$?

Comment: Yes, and this is well-known - see the "Better Results" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate , for instance.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Nice. You could post that as an answer?

Comment: Oh, we have an answer in the same spirit.

Comment: dupe of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090770/a-question-on-prime-density/1090816#1090816, sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, see:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate
--> "Better results"